# Is there a way to do a -Find and Replace- for AWS S3 bucket files

Tags: replace, find

I have hundreds of files I need to "Rename". They all start with the same few letters, and I need to replace these letters with the year - so easy for a find/replace tool. When I rename and save them now it throws me back to the beginning of the listing hundreds of files away.

A find & Replace would mean I could do a batch renaming in one go. I searched for a way to do this, but no luck.

If only the page would not refresh, even S3 browser throws me back to the beginning.

Thanks for your thoughts ~

Comment: You don't say what you've tried so far, but it sounds like you're trying to do this via the console.  I'd recommend having a look at the aws cli https://aws.amazon.com/cli/ or the programming language of your choice with one of the aws sdks https://aws.amazon.com/tools/  With the cli, you should be able to write a script that does what you want.

Comment: .... I don't say what I've tried because - I said, I wasn't finding anything to try.  
But now you have given me something to try :) Thank you, that's a place to start.

Comment: Hum, after looking into aws cli I'm not finding any recognized command for renaming.    I've also looked into S3express, and S3cmd, also no luck.  I've contacted S3browser, and they say "that's a good idea, we will consider adding it for the next version".  So far - No Rename feature.....

Comment: what you need is the aws cli command "mv."  ("mv" is short for "move")  To rename an individual file, you can use a command like this:

aws s3 mv s3://bucket-001/oldname.txt   s3://bucket-001/newname.txt

The next step is to write a script so you can use this to iterate all the files and rename them.  However, this will require some scripting experience.

Comment: Oh that is good to know, I did know about the mv, but alas it leads me back to writing a script :)  I wanted the find/replace to speed things up, me teaching myself to write said script would only be slowing things down.... I just don't have the current skill set to roll my own.  But thank you all - my question has been answered, there is no out-of-the-box solution for this at this time.  Thank you all